# Symfony changing the form that a form render a ManyToOne Field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms

this is my very first question :S

I'm using Symfony2 and i'm having the following trouble

I have two entities related in a ManyToOne relation, I want to make a form for the followin entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\ProductsBundle\Entity\ProductCategory", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $productCategory;
}
```

So i did the following "ProductType"

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('productCategory')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\ProductsBundle\Entity\Product'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_hellobundle_producttype';
    }
}
```

And all works great when i render the form, but now i want to change the widget of the "productCategory" to a text widget, because the user need to write the number that is the primary key of the productCategory.

But when i do it, and complete the form, i got the following error.

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string
>   given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sym2\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php
>   line 1358

Seems like the ORM fails reading a string of the PK, anyone have any little idea of what i must see to fix it. Thanks in advice :)

Comment: you need a little more work than just generating forms from entities, remember you can combine FormTypes , a ProductType can have a CategoryType inside it. check the symfony doc ,it is really well written ( and in french if you are like me ).

Comment: Also check your getters/setters so that they are type-hinted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your product entity has a relation to product category. So your form expects the category to be an entity and not a string. This is why you get the error `expects parameter 1 to be object, string given`.

To avoid this you can remove `setDefaultOptions` method. If you do so the form class will not know anymore that it is associated to a certain entity class. The pitfall of this is, that when you pass the entity to the form class it will not set the fields automatically.

However now you can enter the category id and handle it.

E.g.

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('productCategory');        
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_hellobundle_producttype';
    }
}
```

Now productCategory will be text widget automatically. However you will need to persist it on your own in the controller. But for this you might ask another question.

Notice, when you create the form, don't pass the product object. Have it like this

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), array());
```

Comment: Hi artworkad, thanks for the reply i it's good way for solve this, i was reading deeply the symfony documentation and i found that using data transformers you can  avid this too. So i think that both are good alternatives. Thanks for your reply. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html